# log4net missing log entries

Tags: .net, logging, log4net

I am using log4net version 1.2.15.0 as Nuget and sometimes I miss some log entries.
I am using this throw pythonnet and I have no idea why this is happening.
I have a code like this:

```
logger.Info("reading def");
string textDefinition = FileExtensions.ReadAllTextReadOnly(testPath);
logger.Info("Definition");
logger.Debug(textDefinition);

try
{
    testDefinition = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestSuiteDefinition>(textDefinition);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.Info("failed reload def");
    logger.Info(e.Message);
}
            
logger.Info("test 1");
```

But I have logged this:

```
2016-05-10T18:33:50 reading def
2016-05-10T18:33:50 Definition
2016-05-10T18:33:50 { very long JSON... }
After some time logging continues.
```

This is happening only sometimes in average it is 1/16 runs, in most cases it logs everything.
I turned on log4net internal debug logging, but I am not able to see anything susspicious.

[log4net internal log](http://textuploader.com/5btua)

Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this as DLL and I am importing all classes and methods from python.

So it works like a console aplication.

I have a set logging to a file and internal log4net debug logging is not telling me anything.

I tested that if you lock a logging file it will write something like Unable to log message, but nothing like that is in that internal log debug file.

Weird is that this is happening very random, about 1 of 16 executed tests.

Answer (score -1):

Log4net gather the logs and then insert them together, what i noticed sometimes because of disconnection or anything else, it loses this data...

it also happens a lot with websites (not web application) when the web site recycle..

although i couldn't know what exactly causing this, but i found that if u activate the file log, logs wont be lost...

good luck